# Order issue in AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have the following code that loops through each RSS XML feed URL and render each feed blog entry when it's all finished. On each success ajax call the `channel` is pushed to `xmlDocs` array, because ajax is async operation, the result is not in an order I wanted. I can set `async: false` but this is not a good practice and deprecated across all major browsers. What is a workaround to get this in sync manner? If this is a duplicated question, please point me to the answered question. Many thanks!

```
for (let url in $urls) {
   if (!$urls.hasOwnProperty(url)) continue;
   feedUrls.unshift($urls[url]);
}

feedUrls.forEach((url) => {
   ajaxRequests.push(
      $.ajax({
         method: "GET",
         url: url,
         success: (xml) => {
            let channel = xml.getElementsByTagName("channel")[0];
            xmlDocs.push(channel);
         },
         error: () => {
            $cxNetworkError.removeClass("x-hidden");
         }
      })
   );
});

$.when.apply(null, ajaxRequests).then(() => {
   createBlogEntry(xmlDocs);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out with a workaround.

```
let requestIndex = 0;

let ajaxRequest = function (url) {
   $.get(url).done((xml) => {
      let channel = xml.getElementsByTagName("channel")[0];
      xmlDocs.push(channel);

      requestIndex++;

      if (requestIndex < feedUrls.length) 
         ajaxRequest(feedUrls[requestIndex]);
      else
         createBlogEntry(xmlDocs);
   }).fail(() => {
      $cxNetworkError.removeClass("x-hidden");
   });
};

// Initialize the first ajax request
ajaxRequest(feedUrls[requestIndex]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use counter to make `xmlDoc` array in sync with `ajaxRequests`.

It may look like this (not tested):

`var i = 0;
feedUrls.forEach((url) => {
   ajaxRequests.push(
      $.ajax({
         method: "GET",
         url: url,
         success: (xml) => {
            let channel = xml.getElementsByTagName("channel")[0];
            xmlDocs[i++] = channel; // note this!
         },
         error: () => {
            $cxNetworkError.removeClass("x-hidden");
         }
      })
   );
});
...
i = 0;
$.when.apply(null, ajaxRequests).then(() => {
   createBlogEntry(xmlDocs);
});`